# QoS for site to site VPN

Tags: vpn, qos, sonicwall

Hey guys maybe you could help me.

I have one main site is a clinic where we have a PACS server. So we have 3 more clinics around the country  with VPN to send  pictures to the server. Now we have  4 NSA 220  one in each site. The VPN is working  but  one of the sites is really slow. We have 1MB dedicated line in each site. In the main site we have 10MB.

So I want to apply some kind of Qos to the VPN to guarantee at least 50% of the bandwidth. however I dont know if this going to work because the topology in this clinic is like this.

```
                          Clinic Network  --------Switch                 
                                                    --
                                                    --
         PC with PACS Client-----Sonicwall------Internet router
```

So they share the same exit to the internet with all the traffic in the clinic. The only traffic who  pass through the Sonicwall is the PACS traffic. So probably we have a bottleneck in the internet exit. But that network is beyond my control.

So at least I need to try the Qos. But I don't how to Qos my VPN.

Any idea or suggestion?

Thank you.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a Bandwidth Management Rule (BWM) Rule and apply it to a LAN > VPN firewall rule or DMZ > VPN if you have it in the DMZ. You can customize it for each individual site connection through source and destination or VPN connections as a whole.

BWM Rule should be set to advanced for this to work. If you need further help I recommend looking up implementing BWM on a Sonicwall, or just message me and I'll be glad to help more.

Comment: Should I do it in both sides? the firewall has so many rules from  LAN to VPN. So I not sure in which rule should I apply the BWM.

Comment: If you're only trying to reserve bandwidth at the main site than you only need to do it there. You should create a new firewall rule with the specific ports you need (preferably) so you can give it lower value, higher priority than the already in place rules.